# Comparing 2700+ filenames against 29000+ rows in a db table

Tags: php, mysql, ftp

I have a ftp repository that is currently at 2761 files (PDF files).
I have a MySQL table (a list of those files) that's actually at 29k+ files (it hasn't been parsed since a recent upgrade).
I'd like to provide admins with a one-click script that will do the following:

- 1) Compare the "existing" filenames with the rows in the database table
- 2) Delete any rows that are not in the existing filesystem
- 3) Add a new row for a file that doesn't appear in the database table

This usually is handled by an AppleScript/FolderAction/Perl script method, but it's not perfect (it chokes sometimes when large numbers of files are added at a time - like on heavy news nights).

It takes about 10-20 seconds to build the file list from the FTP repository (using `$file_list = ftp_nlist($conn_id,$target_dir) )`, and I'm not sure how to best go about comparing with the DB table (I'm positive that an `WHERE NOT IN (big_fat_list)` would be a nightmare query to run).

Any suggestions?

Comment: SQL-wise, 29,000 is a small number!  With the proper index(es), the "NOT IN" approach you suggest (assuming the list of current files to be loaded to a work/temporary table), should actually be quite fast, and quite convenient to produce all the INSERT/DELETE and UPDATE that may be necessary in the main table.  Furthermore, all these SQL operations could be initiated from a very few SQL queries invoked from PHP, which would be much faster than "cursoring through" the list at PHP level.

Answer (score 1):

Load the list of filenames into another table, then perform a couple of queries that fulfill your requirements.

Comment: Yeah, I got that answer elsewhere, I think that might have to be the route.
I just added an index on the "filename" column in order to speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

Yup that is the solution. I propose you to use pdo prepared insert statement to reduce time. 
or do what mysqldump does, generate insert into table(column1,column2, ... ) values(),
(),
(),
...
;
insert into ...

you would have to check the maximun values list in mysql site.

Answer (score 0):

I usually dump the recursive directory list with dates and file sizes to a temporary table.  Then I remove items not found:

```
delete
from A
where not exists (
    select null as nothing
    from   temp b
    where  a.key = b.key )
```

Then I update items already there (for file sizes, CRCs):

```
update a set nonkeyfield1 = b.nonkeyfield1, nonkeyfield2 = b.nonkeyfield2
from   a join temp b on a.key = b.key
```

Then I add items found:

```
insert into A ( field, list)
select field, list
from   temp b
where  not exists (
    select null as nothing
    from   A
    where  b.key = a.key )
```

This is from memory, so test it first before you fly.  The select null as nothing keeps you from wasting RAM while you check things.